# "All I've done" or "All what I've done"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence, subjects, syntactic-analysis

Is the "what" required to come after "all"? Are the following sentences grammatically correct? What is the grammar point here? I understood that there should be a subject and a main verb. In this case, should the subject be "all what I've done"? Or "all I've done"?

1) All (what) I've done is sleep.
2) After all (what) I've done, I still fail to ...

Comment: "After all what I've done..." would be perceived as illiterate by the average American English speaker.  You do hear it, but usually only from actors playing "country bumpkins" on TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "*what*" should never appear in these constructions. But you could use "*that*".

> 1) All **that** I've done is sleep.
>
> 2) After all **that** I've done, I still fail to ...

However, it's also fine without.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason? I kept on googling it and interestingly, I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245820/i-want-to-delete-all-what-ive-contributed-in-stackexchange-forums-in-all-forum  Apparently, "what" is used, so is it grammatically incorrect then? But somehow I remember hearing it quite often, and that's why I got confused and started questioning my own usage.

Comment: @Sally: the example you give was written by someone who also wrote _I thinked it well_ and _an user_. I would _not_ assume _anything_ is correct just because someone wrote it on the internet, especially if there are indications that that person is not a native speaker who _is_ paying attention to writing carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples don't look proper. Here are my suggestions:

- All I have done is sleep.
- What I have done is sleep.

Comment: Thanks. What if it follows "after". I believe it's either "all" or "what" in the 1st sentence and both of the suggestions provided by you. But somehow it sounds awkward if it's "After all I've done, I still failed the competition."

Comment: @Sally I would say: After all *that* I HAD done, I still failed the competition. I think someone else might give you a better explanation of ‘what’’s usage.